# Image and Input field

Tags: html, css

This is my second question about the same, I just don't know how I can edit it and make it bump up in the list or does that happen automatically? ...

Anyway onto the actual question, I have a image and input box both inside a span now I want to display them next to eachother.

The image is 48x48 and the input field should fill the remaining width.
As the code is now it does not break on zoom and it should be like that.

If i add width: 100%; to the input box then it will break on zooming and I don't get why I want it to fill 100% of the remaining width.

HTML:

```
<div id="vault_chat">
    <div id="vault_chat_header">
        <span class="user_avatar"><img src="<%tdir%>img/default_avatar.png" alt="Default Avatar" /></span>
        <span class="vault_chat_text_field"><input type="text" value="Enter a message..." /></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#vault_chat {

}

#vault_chat_header {
    height: 48px; //tried a fixed height here but it just goes outside the header.
}

.vault_chat_text_field input[type=text] {
    vertical-align: top;
}

.user_avatar img {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
}
```

If you have a solution, please demonstrate this for me in a fiddle.

Comment: How about : http://jsfiddle.net/4NPwj/

Comment: Works but then the image's width decreases on zoom cause of it being percent, if i change it to 48 pixels then the input field breaks on zoom.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I would use Nicole Sullivan's `media` object abstraction. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HEF9g/) (for reference).

HTML:

```
<div class="media">
  <a href="#" class="img"><img src="http://placehold.it/48x48" alt="" /></a>
  <div class="bd"><input type="text"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.media {margin:10px;}
.media, .bd {overflow:hidden; _overflow:visible; zoom:1;}
.media .img {float:left; margin-right: 10px;}
.media .img img {display:block;}
.media .imgExt {float:right; margin-left: 10px;}
input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for the note and explanation. I keep forgetting. :/ (I've ammended my answer to include the code)